# Brake lever and shifter for bullhorn

Tags: brakes, shifter

I have a Sora 3500 set on my bike except for the shifters, which are Alivio ST-M310 and a 22.2mm flat bar.  Now I have a new bullhorn which I would like to install, but the old shifters don't fit, because the diameter of the bullhorn is 23.8mm.

I would like to have the brake and the shifter at the end of the bar, somting like this [image](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/1337/handlebars.jpg). I thought that a bar-end indexed shifter and TT brake lever would fit quite well. I have a 2x8 gear system so, I think a Shimano Ultegra 6480 Triple 8sp Bar End Shifter would be perfect.

But I can't find a TT lever-like brake that has a mounting ring rather than plugging in to the end of the bar.

Is there a brake lever (for caliper brakes) I could look for so that both (brake & shifter) can be mounted at the bar-end?

**UPDATE**

After some search I found two solutions: one explained well [here](http://www.ratracecycles.com/tag/bullhorn-bars/),
another solution is [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7pGA7xe0R3HQm9ZMEd6MHlfaXM/edit?usp=sharing), and here the brakes are Reverse Brake Lever.

*Where can I found a reverse brake lever with clamp mount, and not internal handlebar wedge-sleeve mount?*

I think, I found the answer, but can you correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: can someone add a tag: bullhorn, bar-end-shifter, and TT-lever? :)

Answer (score 2):

The levers in the first post that you linked to appear to be [Cane Creek Crosstop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MVTLPW0) (interrupter) levers. Tektro, Paul, and probably others as well, also make levers like this. They usually work by pressing on the cable housing (effectively making it longer), which is split at the lever. It looks like the levers in the photo are being used as conventional levers and are pulling on the cable itself – the cable appears to dead ends in the barrel adjuster of the levers rather than passing through as it would in a conventional interrupter lever setup.

Comment: I'v seen that cross-top levers can be used like that. But is that as comfortable as a TT lever? Jtek AeroBrake is that kind of lever but it is only for  22.2mm.

Comment: The levers in your photo are Cane Creek CrossTops. If they look good to you, they would be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, there are [Shimano Metrea ST-U5060](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/metrea-u5000/ST-U5060-R.html) brifters which fill this gap - but only for bikes with disc brakes.