# Are there rim brakes for road bikes compatible to Shimano hydraulic brake levers / brifters?

Tags: shifter, brake-levers, triathlon, brifters

Are there any rim brake calipers with road-style mounting compatible to Shimano hydraulic brake levers, specifically [ST-U5060](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/metrea-u5000/ST-U5060-R.html)?

- are Magura ST-06 / ST-08 compatible?
  people combine Magura disc callipers with shimano levers succesfully, dubbed "shigura", but I couldn't find a hint of anyone having combined ST-06/08 with any other lever. I guess they're too uncommon for this.

I'm looking for a way to have both shift- and brake levers on a triathlon bar's horns, like [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41998/how-to-mount-tt-shifters-and-tt-brake-levers-together) or this [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35067/brake-lever-and-shifter-for-bullhorn/65020#65020). To my knowledge, there's only:

- the ST-U5060 that's only for hydraulic disc brakes
- a combination of brake levers clamping on the horn outside and SRAM shifters 
  -I couldn't find the brake levers.
- drop bar brifters on the horns
   (which results in an awkward angle of the levers on my particular triathlon bar)

Comment: I realize this is basically a product recommendation question, but there are several variants of the problem I want to solve on bicycles.stackexchange, plus with these Metreo brifters there's a reatively new product which would solve the problem / answer the questions, but only for disc-brake-compatible bikes. So I hope this question is ok.

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer is no. A cable brake lever will pull cable when you squeeze the lever. A hydraulic lever will compress hydraulic fluid. Those are rather different things mechanically. Why does the lever have to be hydraulic if you are using rim brakes?

Comment: @WeiwenNg OP is looking to use Matrea brifters which are designed for bullhorn type bars on city/urban bikes, and mount them on tri/aero bars. Matrea only has  hydraulic disk brake variant.  Hydraulic rim brakes are a thing, Magura being the most well known manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

I would pick up a pair of cyclocross-style brakes levers that are designed to mount on the flat part of the bar and run inline with the brake cables. You can also mount them to the end of the bar and just have the cable terminate at the lever. The angle might not be quite right with the bullhorns, but some levers come with an adjustment screw that lets you set the default position of the lever. I would make sure to get some like that. And then you can just use whatever bar-end shifters you want.